# How to ensure limited concurrent requests to a webservice in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, concurrency

I want to ensure no more than 10 concurrent requests per second transfered to a webservice?.I try to use mutex class,but failed. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Show us your attempt and point us to what *exactly* failed.

Comment: Also, what kind of web service? WCF? ASMX? REST?

Comment: Suppose it's REST and we don't know the reponse time of the service.How to control it, make sure no more than 10 requests per second?And let other reuqests wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

[`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) class can help you only if you want to synchronize threads accross the processes.
To add restriction of maximum of simultaneously threads running use [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) class.

Simple overviewы can be found here:

- [lock vs Monitor vs Mutex vs Semaphore](http://sarveshknet.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/lock-vs-monitor-vs-mutex-vs-semaphore/)
- [Overview of Synchronization Primitives (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

MSDN example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
    // A semaphore that simulates a limited resource pool. 
    // 
    private static Semaphore _pool;

    // A padding interval to make the output more orderly. 
    private static int _padding;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a semaphore that can satisfy up to three 
        // concurrent requests. Use an initial count of zero, 
        // so that the entire semaphore count is initially 
        // owned by the main program thread. 
        //
        _pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);

        // Create and start five numbered threads.  
        // 
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Worker));

            // Start the thread, passing the number. 
            //
            t.Start(i);
        }

        // Wait for half a second, to allow all the 
        // threads to start and to block on the semaphore. 
        //
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        // The main thread starts out holding the entire 
        // semaphore count. Calling Release(3) brings the  
        // semaphore count back to its maximum value, and 
        // allows the waiting threads to enter the semaphore, 
        // up to three at a time. 
        //
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread calls Release(3).");
        _pool.Release(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    private static void Worker(object num)
    {
        // Each worker thread begins by requesting the 
        // semaphore.
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} begins " +
            "and waits for the semaphore.", num);
        _pool.WaitOne();

        // A padding interval to make the output more orderly. 
        int padding = Interlocked.Add(ref _padding, 100);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} enters the semaphore.", num);

        // The thread's "work" consists of sleeping for  
        // about a second. Each thread "works" a little 
        // longer, just to make the output more orderly. 
        //
        Thread.Sleep(1000 + padding);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} releases the semaphore.", num);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} previous semaphore count: {1}",
            num, _pool.Release());
    }
}
```

Comment: The result depends on the response time.If the webservice(e.g. REST) response in 0.1 seconds.In this Case,there will be 30 requests in 1 second.Could this be controled in 10 requests in 1 second?Should I create a concurrent queue?

Comment: @flyingfireQandA No, this approach doesn't include time limitations. I think you should google for the `throttling` or something similar for it, or create custom queue.